# Function " was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm new to C++ and I am attempting to write a program that simulates a football game. I'm getting a compiler error that says the functions get_rank, get_player, and get_name are not declared in this scope. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Player {
    int playerNum;
    string playerPos;
    float playerRank;
    public:
        void set_values(int, string, float);
        float get_rank(){ return playerRank; };
};

class Team {
    Player team[];
    string teamName;
    public:
        void set_values(Player[],string);
        Player get_player(int a) { return team[a]; };
        string get_name() { return teamName; };
};


void play(Team t1, Team t2){
    float t1rank = 0.0;
    float t2rank = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
        t1rank += get_rank(get_player(t1, i));
    }
    for(int j=0; j<11; j++){
        t2rank += get_rank(get_player(t2, j));
    }
    if(t1rank>t2rank){
        cout << get_name(t1) + " wins!";
    }
    else if(t2rank>t1rank){
        cout << get_name(t2) + " wins!";
    }
    else{
        cout << "It was a tie!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind that you are returning objects by value, not by reference. This means that code like `++t1.get_player(0).playerRank;` will *not* modify the first player's rank.

Comment: I'm not trying to modify the player's rank, but to add up the rank of all players on the team.

Comment: I'm aware of that, just mentioned it so you don't trip over that in some other situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you want to do something like:

```
    t1rank += t1.get_player(i).get_rank();
```

In C++, method calls are of the form `object.method(args)`. In your case, you have two method calls, one where `object` is `t1` and the method is `get_player`, and the second where the object is the return value of the previous call, and the method is `get_rank`.